# jquery added button flicker and prevent some clicks - mediaelement.js

Tags: jquery, mediaelement.js

I want to show a button at a specific time during a video shown with mediaelement.js.

I have added an event listener for time update and add the button code when currentTime is at the specific time.

```
        $('video').mediaelementplayer({
            enableAutosize: true,
            features: ['playpause','volume'],
            alwaysShowControls: false,

            success: function(mediaElement, domObject) {

                    mediaElement.addEventListener('timeupdate', function(e) {

                    var currentTime = mediaElement.currentTime;
                    var msg = '<a href="url-link" target="_blank" class="btn">Click to see</a>';
                    var empty = '';

                    if( currentTime > (120)) {
                        $("#offerArea").html(msg);                          
                    } else {
                        $("#offerArea").html(empty);
                    }       

                 }, false);

        });
```

The problem is that the button "flicker" when hovering over it, and does not work all the time you click when the video is playing. If I stop the video the button works all the time.

http://jsfiddle.net/ronjo/owp191Ld/1/

Comment: Please set up some demo using your HTML and JavaScript, so we can see what's going wrong in your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to be [working just fine](http://jsfiddle.net/m3xf9px0/) in general. But since it doesn't work for you, try to set a variable when you display your link to make sure it only happens once and not all the time while the video is playing.

```
var buttonVisible = false;

$('video').mediaelementplayer({
    enableAutosize: true,
    features: ['playpause', 'volume'],
    alwaysShowControls: false,

    success: function (mediaElement, domObject) {
        mediaElement.addEventListener('canplay', function () {
            mediaElement.play();
        }, false);
        mediaElement.addEventListener('timeupdate', function (e) {

            var currentTime = mediaElement.currentTime;
            var msg = '<a href="http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26501102/jquery-added-button-flicker-and-prevent-some-clicks-mediaelement-js" target="_blank" class="btn">Click to see</a>';
            var empty = '';

            if (currentTime > (1) && buttonVisible == false) {
                buttonVisible = true;
                $("#offerArea").html(msg);
            }

        }, false)

    }
});
```

**On [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/m3xf9px0/1/).**

Comment: I have the same issue with your jsfiddle code.
I am on a Mac running OSX 10.9.5 and tried with Safari v7.1, Firefox 32.0.3 and Google Chrome v38.0.2125.104.
https://www.dropbox.com/sh/qnosydhgmnj8khq/AAC6iLXrCX1BCanWCIXOwqlwa?dl=0

Comment: Very interesting. I'm on 10.9.4 and it works just fine in all browsers. Might be a performance issue if my computer manages to redraw the element fast enough but yours doesn't. Does the second JSFIDDLE link work, at the bottom of my answer? In that case, as I mentioned in my post, you are redrawing the link thousands of times since you keep updating #offerArea every **millisecond** after 120 seconds. You should update offerArea once, then set a variable so it doesn't happen every following millisecond. Something like my example.

Comment: Yes, now I see you had two examples. Your second fiddle work.
But does it really update every millisecond? I thought it updated only on the time update event, about 4 times per second...